# Upgrading from windows 10 stuck at 64% bootloop (Solution needed without using USB)

Tags: windows-10

My friend is upgrading from win7 to win10, and at 64% it stays and keeps booting endlessly. How can I resolve this issue without a USB?

I'll give more details as you need them, since I'm not sure what you would need in this situation.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a CD or DVD drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need ***some*** interface to resolve this. Your options:

1) Clean install using a DVD. (Can backup files before hand using a live linux if necessary)

2) Remove the hard drive and attach to another PC. Reinstall

Other than that, I don't know what the question is supposed to ask. Why not USB anyway? Broken ports?

Comment: It was for a friend and he didn't want to use USB at first....until I contacted him again and he said he did.